# How to use SourceForge?

Tags: svn, repository, cvs, sourceforge

Okay, I want to use SourceForge to host my source for a program, but I have no idea how to use SVN or CVS. I tried looking at tutorials, but they all seem to be oriented on retrieving source, not adding to it. As of now, the repository is empty (no source there), so how do I add my source files? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you only consider SVN or CVS? Ought to give DVCS a go...

Comment: Don't use CVS for new projects. Subversion can everything CVS can, and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
svn import **folder** -m "comment here"
```

to import a folder into your repository (to start one).

you can also use

```
svn add **folder**
```

to add files and folders to repository then use

```
svn commit  -m "comoment here"
```

But the easiest way would be to use a GUI application, like tortoiseSVN on windows and svnX on OS X if you're not familiar with SVN.

Comment: One more thing, what url do I give it?

Comment: Google it there are plenty, I use subversive inside eclipse for projects. the URL inside the repository, e.g svn://code.google.com/myrepo/url

Comment: It worked, but after I input my password, it asks for the username again. If I give my username and password again, it returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

My Suggestion is to use a graphical SVN-Client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), go to >> "Repo Browser" and enter the following

```
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/{Your Project Name Goes Here}/code/trunk
```

You'll then be prompted of your username and passcode.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
svn import file url -m "Comment Goes here"
```

So lets say I wanted to to upload a file called *file*, to a url *url*, you would use the above command.

[SVN help](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/)

The first time you import or check in, you will need to do --username *username* and/or not --password *password*, you can drop password, and be prompted for it after you have established connection if you so choose.

```
svn import file --username bob --password bobiscool url -m "Comment"
```

If you dont use -m you will go into this gnarly to navigate nano screen asking for a comment, so it is best to remember to add -m.

Comment: Okay, I found the url, and connected, and inputted my password. But now it's asking for a username again? Here's what it says: Authentication realm: <https://name.svn.sourceforge.net:443> SourceForge Subversion area

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to Subversion, I strongly advise you to read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) to learn more about Subversion and version-control in general. It is the **MUST READ reference book** which will help you to understand common version-control practices and the common workflow. SVNBook is the Bible of SVN and must-read for Subversion administrators and users, in fact.

Chapters you may find helpful as a novice Subversion user:

- ["Fundamental Concepts"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html),
- ["Basic Work Cycle"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html),
- ["Branching and Merging"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html).